# Complex conditions in ifeval::[] in asciidoctor

Tags: java, maven, asciidoc, asciidoctor

Probably a stupid question, but how can I make a more complex ifeval conditions in asciidoctor ?

For example

```
:x: (this is passed from maven POM)

ifeval::['{x}' != 'C2' or '{x}' != 'C3']
...
endif::[]
```

---

Despite it is written in the asciidoctor user manual about the conditional operators:

> "The operators follow the same rules as operators in Ruby."

It's seems "and", "or", "&&", "||" are not part of the rules ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is not supported for ifeval:: at the moment -> https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1786

It is supported for ifdef and ifndef though and can be used for example:

---

```
ifeval::[...]
:attr1:
endif::[]

ifeval::[...]
:attr2:
endif::[]

OR
ifdef::attr1,attr1[] 
...
endif::[]

AND
ifdef::attr1+attr1[] 
...
endif::[]
```

---

Which I think a bit of a inconvenience.